# Number of positive integer solutions to the equation $a_1+a_2+\cdots+a_n=k$, where $k\geq n$

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-number-theory

I was wondering if there is a formula for counting the number of positive integers solutions to the equation
\begin{equation}
a_1+a_2+\cdots+a_n=k,
\end{equation}
where $n\leq  k$, $k\in \mathbb{N}$ and $n\geq 2$. The case when $n>k$ is impossible since the least positive value that can assume all the $a_i$ are equal to $1$, and adding these we get $n=k$, a contradiction, so it does not have any solutions, but what about the case when $k\geq n$? For example, I wish to find a general formula for counting the positive integers solutions to equations such as $a+b=5$ and $a+b+c+d=12$, that is, where the number of variables is less than the constant positive integer. Any help or hints given will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hint:Since $k\geq n,$ you can first fill in each of $k$ boxes with one ball.

Comment: This is a very popular problem which is Euler’s candy division problem. You can search it very easily.

Comment: See Stars and Bars theory, 
[here](https://brilliant.org/wiki/integer-equations-star-and-bars/) and
[here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)), and consider the change of variable $$y_i = x_i - 1 \implies y_1 + \cdots y_n = k-n.$$  Here, each $y_i$ variable must be a non-negative integer, so the solution is then immediate.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Imagine we have placed $k$ balls in line,
$$\text{ooooooo}\quad (k=7).$$
Positive-integer solutions of $a_1+\cdots+a_n=k$ correspond to partitions of the balls into $n$ parts. For example,
$$\text{oo}|\text{o}|\text{oooo}\quad (n=3,k=7)$$
corresponds to the solution $(2,1,4)$ of the equation
$a_1+a_2+a_3=7$.
We can choose $n-1$ places to put $n-1$ walls, among the $k-1$ midpoints of two balls next to each other. Therefore, the number of solution is the binomial coefficient
$$\begin{pmatrix}k-1\\n-1\end{pmatrix}.$$